# HLookup function returns N/A when Lookup value exists

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following table:

[image]

with the help of HLookup I'm trying to find a value related to each shop

```
Dim V1 As Variant
With Worksheets("Sales")
Set Lookup_Range = .Range("A1:H6")

    V1 = Application.HLookup("Shop 1", Lookup_Range, 2, False)

--checking if the value exists        
 If IsError(V1) Then
    .Cells(1, 20) = 0
 Else
    .Cells(1, 20) = V1
 End If
 End With
```

The function doesn't find the value, even though the "Shop 1" exists. Without "IsError(V1)" I get N/A. I don't understand what is wrong and where could be a problem?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There must be a difference between the two values. Perhaps a leading or trailing space, or a char(160) rather than a true space in the name.

Comment: and how can I figure it out and/or fix it?

Comment: Start by checking the values on the worksheet carefully

Comment: everything seems okay

Comment: What does this display: `msgbox Worksheets("Sales").Range("A1").Value = "Shop 1"`

Comment: it returns "not correct"

Comment: Which confirms my initial answer. What do these return: `msgbox Worksheets("Sales").Range("A1").Value`, `msgbox len(Worksheets("Sales").Range("A1").Value)`, `msgbox ascw(mid$(Worksheets("Sales").Range("A1").Value, 5, 1))`

Comment: 1st returns: message box "Assignment group"

Comment: 2nd and 3rd return numbers

Comment: So which cell should contain "shop 1"?